# Play framework - RabbitMQ Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: scala, playframework, rabbitmq

I am using java-rabbitmq-client in an Play Framework scala application.

```
"com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "4.0.0"
```

Very often I get this exception and after few hours without any code change or settings change it connects and works properly.

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[warn] c.r.c.i.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Socket closed)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at utils.mq.email.MQEmailConsumer$.start(MQEmailConsumer.scala:17)
        at utils.App$.main(App.scala:20)
        at utils.App.main(App.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:76)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:110)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
```

The code to connect to RabbitMQ is as follows:

```
object MQConnection {

  val factory: ConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()

  factory.setUri(MQConfig.host)
  factory.setUsername(MQConfig.username)
  factory.setPassword(MQConfig.password)
  factory.setVirtualHost(MQConfig.virtualHost)

  factory.setConnectionTimeout(MQConfig.connectionTimeout)

  val conn: Connection = factory.newConnection()

  def getChannel(queueName: String, exchangeName: String, routingKey: String): Channel = {
    Logger.info(s"Creating channel with queue ${ queueName }, exchangeName - ${exchangeName}, routingKey - ${routingKey}")
    val channel: Channel = conn.createChannel()
    channel.exchangeDeclare(
      exchangeName,
      MQConfig.exchangeType,
      MQConfig.durable
    )
    channel.queueDeclare(queueName, MQConfig.durable, false, false, null)
    channel.queueBind(queueName, exchangeName, routingKey)

    channel
  }

}
```

The `/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log` has the following details logged when trying to start a consumer:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 11-Feb-2017::18:54:43 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.22922.0> (127.0.0.1:63334 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 11-Feb-2017::18:54:51 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.22922.0> (127.0.0.1:63334 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

The logs in `/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log`:

```
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 11-Feb-2017::18:54:43 ===
          supervisor: {<0.22920.0>,rabbit_connection_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.22921.0>},
                       {name,helper_sup},
                       {mfargs,{rabbit_connection_helper_sup,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,intrinsic},
                       {shutdown,infinity},
                       {child_type,supervisor}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 11-Feb-2017::18:54:43 ===
          supervisor: {<0.22920.0>,rabbit_connection_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.22922.0>},
                       {name,reader},
                       {mfargs,
                           {rabbit_reader,start_link,
                               [<0.22921.0>,
                                {acceptor,{127,0,0,1},5672},
                                #Port<0.30086>]}},
                       {restart_type,intrinsic},
                       {shutdown,30000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
```

Can you please help. This has been very annoying and sometimes it takes a day or two before it makes a successful connection.

Comment: You are creating the connection once for your application: `val conn: Connection = factory.newConnection()`. This means that, when object `MQConnection` is initialized, a new connection will be used and it won't be renewed until your application is restarted. Is this what you really want? Anyway, looking at RabbitMQ docs, you should probably read about [heartbeats timeouts](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#heartbeats-timeout) and also [how to recovery from network failures](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery).

Comment: Adding recovery from network failures did the trick.